# JMapper XML configuration for nested source and target?

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

Does JMapper support mapping nested objects (source or target). Can anyone help with an example if it is possible?

Source:

```
{
"firstName" : "John"
"lastName" : "Wick"
}
```

Target:

```
{
    "customerDetails": {

        "customerFirstName": null,
        "customerLastName": null

    }
}
```

I want to map firstName from source to customerFirstName in the target object using XML configuration.